# Stacking a HStack below a ZStack in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, hstack, zstack

Disclaimer: New to SwiftUI

I know a `ZStack()` view allows me to overlap views, which is what I want for the heading section of the app.

I set the `ZStack()` to not take up the entire height and had expected an `HStack()`, placed after the `ZStack()` to do just that, appear after. Instead it also overlaps with the ZStack.

I'm sure it's a simple solution to co-exist. Image and code below.

```
var body: some View {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                    Ellipse()
                    .fill(self.bgColor)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 1.4, height: geometry.size.height * 0.28)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2.35, y: geometry.size.height * 0.1)
                    .shadow(radius: 3)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                    
                    HStack(alignment: .top) {
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                            Text(self.title)
                                .font(.title)
                                .fontWeight(.bold)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                            
                            Text(self.subtitle)
                                .font(.subheadline)
                                .fontWeight(.regular)
                                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        }
                        .padding(.leading, 25)
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                        Spacer()
                        VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                            Image("SettingsIcon")
                                .resizable()
                                .scaledToFit()
                                .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                        }
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                        .padding(.trailing, 25)
                    }
                }
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Text(self.title)
                        .font(.title)
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                }
     
            }
        }
```

[image]

Comment: You can use .zIndex()

Comment: @AdR I'll look into that and go from there, thanks for the input

Comment: @AdR zIndex is for layering views inside a ZStack. I wanted the HStack() to align itself below the ZStack(). See the blue outline of the ZStack in the image above. I want to add a view below that, not on top of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following code using a top `VStack` and closing the `GeometryReader` before the last `HStack`:

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {  // <-- here
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack(alignment: .topLeading) {
                Ellipse()
                  .fill(self.bgColor)
                    .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 1.4, height: geometry.size.height * 0.28)
                    .position(x: geometry.size.width / 2.35, y: geometry.size.height * 0.1)
                    .shadow(radius: 3)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                
                HStack(alignment: .top) {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text(self.title)
                            .font(.title)
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        
                        Text(self.subtitle)
                            .font(.subheadline)
                            .fontWeight(.regular)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    }
                    .padding(.leading, 25)
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                        Image("SettingsIcon")
                            .resizable()
                            .scaledToFit()
                            .frame(width: 30, height: 30)
                    }
                    .padding(.top, 20)
                    .padding(.trailing, 25)
                }
            }.fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
        } // <-- here end GeometryReader
        
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            Text(self.title)
                .font(.title)
                .fontWeight(.bold)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
        }
    } // <-- here end VStack
}
```